# pull remote from github with phpseclib

Tags: github, ssh, phpseclib

I am trying to auto update a website from remote git repo. As it's on a shared hosting i use a webhook on github & phpseclib 1.0. Here is my code:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2(SITE_DOMAIN);
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('/home/'.SSH_USERNAME.'/.ssh/'.KEYPAIR_NAME));
if (!$ssh->login(SSH_USERNAME, $key)) {
 throw new Exception('Failed to login');
 exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->write("cd ~/source\n");
echo $ssh->write("git pull origin master\n");
```

the git command won't run. but when i do a git pull manually from terminal it works 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
echo $ssh->write("cd ~/source\n");
echo $ssh->write("git pull origin master\n");
```

Usually with interactive shells you need to wait for the prompt before you send the next command. Try something like this:

```
$ssh->read('#[prompt]#');
echo $ssh->write("cd ~/source\n");
$ssh->read('#[prompt]#');
echo $ssh->write("git pull origin master\n");
```

Sometimes identifying what the prompt is is easy - sometimes it's less so. Like if the prompt has colored text in it that would mean that the prompt is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me

```
$ssh->setTimeout(2);
echo $ssh->write("cd ~/source\n");
$ssh->read();
echo $ssh->write("git pull origin master\n");
```